# How can Python determine the date of a provincial holiday

Tags: python

In Canada, some holidays are provincial holidays, like civic holiday in Ontario. So given a province in Canada, how can you check if a date is a holiday for this province. I used the holidays module, it seems it gets holidays for Canada, but not each province.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `subdiv` to get the holidays for a specific province.

```py
import holidays
ca_on_holidays = holidays.country_holidays('CA', subdiv='ON') 
# subdiv can be one of AB, BC, MB, NB, NL, NS, NT, NU, ON, PE, QC, SK, YT
# ON is the default
```